# Lagrange form of Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have to find minimal number for h, for numerical differentiation using formula:
$$f'(x_0+\frac{3h}{4}) = \frac{y(x_0+h)-y(x_0)}{h}$$. I have the solution of this example, I just have one question that considers Teylor polynomial.
So, let $x_1  = x_0+\frac{3h}{4}$. Now $y(x_0+h)=y(x_1)+y'(x_1)\frac{h}{4}+\frac{y''(\alpha)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{16}$, and then it is written that $\alpha\in(x_0,x_0+h)$, which confuses me, shouldn't it be $(x_0+\frac{3h}{4},x_0+h)$?